# Issues creating custom column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am currently working with a data set that has similar to the below fields:

| user | activity | date of activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jason | Activity A | 12/1/2022 |
| Jason | Activity B | 12/1/2022 |
| Jason | Activity C | 12/1/2022 |

Each user will have multiple(different types) of activities on the same day. I am trying create a column that shows if a user has had activity on any given day but I don't want it to count all the activities just show 1 if he has activity on that day regardless of type or number of activities per day. So for Jason I would need it to show count of 1 for 12/01/2022 even though he has
had 3 activities that day.

Comment: You could create  a table with SUMMARIZECOLUMNS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try.